# Closed Subspaces with Zero Distance on Unit Sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $K_1, K_2$ be two closed, linear subspaces of a (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space $H$. Further, suppose that there exists a sequence of unit vectors $(x_n) \subset K_1, (y_n) \subset K_2$ such that $||x_n - y_n|| \rightarrow 0$. In other words, the closed, convex subsets $K_1 \cap S, K_2 \cap S$ have zero infimal distance where $S$ is the unit sphere in $H$.

Now, I have the following questions.

1. I know that in general $K_1, K_2$ may only have trivial intersection, however I do not know any examples. Could someone please provide some simple examples of such a case?
2. Are there any "handy" conditions that ensures that $K_1, K_2$ must have non-trivial intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the orthonormal basis, $K_1$ be the closed subspace spanned by $\{e_{2n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $K_2$ be the subspace spanned by the orthonormal system $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty,$ where $f_n=(\cos{\textstyle {1\over n}})e_{2n}+(\sin\textstyle {{1\over n}})e_{2n-1}.$ Then $K_1\cap K_2=\{0\}.$ Indeed every element $v$ of $K_2$ is of the form $$v=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nf_n,\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2<\infty $$ Hence $$v=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n( 
{\textstyle \cos{1\over n}})e_{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n( 
 \sin \textstyle {{1\over n}})e_{2n-1}$$ Assume $v\in K_1.$ Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n( 
\textstyle {\sin{1\over n}})e_{2n-1}=0 $$ Hence $a_n=0$ for every $n,$ which gives $v=0.$ Moreover $\|e_{2n}-f_n\|\to 0.$

Concerning the second question there is only the trivial condition that there are unit vectors $u\in K_1$ and $v\in K_2$ such that $\|u-v\|=0,$ i.e. $u=v.$

Comment: Thanks, that is a very nice general example! Do you have any ideas about any conditions that can be placed to ensure that $K_1, K_2$ don't have trivial intersection?

Comment: I can see only the  trivial condition. See the last part of the answer. I do not think there is any reasonable nontrivial one.